# Correct way to announce a theorem

Tags: article-writing

Reading the following statement :

> **Theorem :**
>
> An operator $A$ has the property $P$ if $\underset{\lambda \rightarrow 0}{%
> \lim }\left( A-\lambda \right) ^{-1}$ exists.

Does the reader understand that $\left( A-\lambda \right) ^{-1}$ is defined
on a neighborhood of $0$ ?

Or the correct way to announce the theorem must be like :

> **Theorem :**
>
> An operator $A$ has the property $P$ if there is some neighborood $V\subset%
> %TCIMACRO{\U{2102} }%
> %BeginExpansion
> \mathbb{C}
> %EndExpansion
> $ of $0$ such that $\left( A-\lambda \right) ^{-1}$ and $\underset{\lambda
> \rightarrow 0}{\lim }\left( A-\lambda \right) ^{-1}$ exist.

Short announcements are more beautiful. If there are any rules to follow,
can somebody tell me about ?

Comment: It depends on the context. Then both statements are fine.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as needing more focus; it is currently too broad. As @Wuestenfux addressed, it really depends on the context.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish I hesitate before posting this question, because I you said, it depends on the context. What I'm asking in fact is : if it is possible to avoid mentioning less important details when writing down a theorem. So, I found the answer of Gibbs very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good habit when writing down a theorem is to add the essential details about the objects involved in the statement. Other properties may be added elsewhere or not added at all if not strictly important.

In both cases, it is not clear where the operator $A$ lives. That is an essential thing to add so as to make the reader able to understand why property $P$ is meaningful for $A$ or why $(A-\lambda)^{-1}$ makes sense. I think it is clear that $(A-\lambda)^{-1}$ must be defined around $\lambda = 0$ in order to be able to take the limit.

Comment: thank you so much